# Golang nested structs unmarshaling with underscores

Tags: json, struct, go, instagram-api

I am writing an app using the Instagram API. 
I am receiving a JSON request and that gets `Unmarshal`'ed into nested structs.

```
// the nested structs
type ResponseData struct {
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    Link string `json:"link"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
    User struct {
        FullName       string `json:"full_name"`
        ID             int    `json:"id"`
        ProfilePicture string `json:"profile_picture"`
        Username       string `json:"username"`
    }
    Images struct {
        Standard_Resolution struct {
            URL string `json:"url"`
        }
    }
}
```

For the Image url to be added it needs to have the underscore in `Standard_Resolution` , I am using [Go Plus](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus) Package for Atom and I get the lint warning:

> don't use underscores in Go names; struct field Standard_Resolution
>   should be StandardResolution

Is there another way for me fix the error and still have the value in my struct.

**Update:**

I can add an identifier after the last brace for `StandardResolution`.

```
StandardResolution struct {
    URL string `json:"url"`
} `json:"standard_resolution"`
```

Comment: I think you can use tags on struct types too. Just "rename" your StandardResolution struct via `json: "Standard_Resolution"`. Go is really dead regular. I didn't try it .

Comment: A minimal working example would help on debugging with a plain go compiler. My golang.org Language Specification says http://golang.org/ref/spec#IdentifierList that underscore is a valid part of an identifier

Comment: But adding a `json:"Standard_Resolution"` should help too and should make things clearer.

Comment: I didnt realize that I could rename my struct by adding ``json:"standard_resolution"`` after the brace, I was adding it after the word `struct`, hence i was getting an error. thanks @volker @ikrabbe

Comment: You realize that if you translate into non-nested structure definitions, as in my attempt to answer, below.

Comment: @ikrabbe The "no underscores" issue is a *style* recommendation from `go vet` (which Go Plus would run) rather than a "breaks the OP's program" issue.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway it is easier to read if you don't use nested structs.

```
type RDUser struct { ... }
type RDStandardResolution struct { ... }
type RDImages struct {
    StandardResolition RDStandardResolution `json:"standard_resolution"`
}
type ResponseData struct {
    ...
    User RDUser `json:"user"`
    Images RDImages `json:"images"`
}
```